# jQuery API call to Entity Framework API Put method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using jquery to make an API call to an Entity Framework API Controller and I am trying to call the Put Method:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult PutProfileIDClass(int id, ProfileIDClass profileIDClass)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (id != profileIDClass.id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    db.Entry(profileIDClass).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!ProfileIDClassExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

But when I make the API call via jQuery I get this error: 405 (Method Not Allowed)

What Am I doing wrong?

Here is my API call

```
 var data = {
                        id: result.data[0].id,
                        profileID: result.data[0].profileID,
                        taken: 'true'
                    };

                    var json = JSON.stringify(data);

$.ajax({
                        url: '/api/ProfileIDAPI?id=' + result.data[0].id,
                        type: 'PUT',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: json,
                        success: function (results) {
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a `PUT` request you should use the `method: 'PUT'` as part of your `$.ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/ProfileIDAPI?id=' + result.data[0].id,
    method: 'PUT',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: json,
    success: function (results) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have it installed on IIS? In that case, you have to configure it to handle your "PUT" request.

Right click on your website in the sidebar and go to properties.

Go to the "Home Directory" Tab

In the "applications settings", click on the "configuration" button

In the "Applications configuration" Window, there should be a Mappings Tab

Simply choose which file extensions you want to have mapped (in my case i wanted ASP to map GET, PUT, POST & DELETE), comma delimited. And thats it, not even a restart required.

Hope this helps